# QCheckBox и Excel таблица

Tags: python, pyqt5, excel, qtablewidget, qcheckbox

Имеется динамическая `exсel` таблица, с изменяющимся количеством строк (наименование колонок изменить нельзя, скачивается с файла в таблицу `QTableWidget`). Необходимо для дальнейшей обработки определить, какие строки помечены  `CheckBox`.

*Трудности*:

1. `CheckBox` отображается в первой колонке с данными, хотелось бы что бы располагался до номера строки. Таких примеров не попадалось, возможно ли это?
2. Не пойму, как корректно  определить, какие строки в таблице имеют статус `CheckBox: True` по кнопке (в момент установки/снятия CheckBox’а - работает), при условии, что кнопка и таблица находятся в разных классах.
3. Как можно установить и снять `CheckBox` всех имеющихся строк галкой «Весь список» (без постоянного отслеживания манипуляции мыши).
4. В статусбаре элементы добавляются справа, а команда `statusBar().insertPermanentWidget(1, _ )` – делает привязку в крайнюю левую позицию из имеющихся. Можно привязать элемент к левому краю рамки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример таблицы: [https://dropmefiles.com/YK7zT[2]](https://dropmefiles.com/YK7zT%5B2%5D) Пример кода:

**m3.py**

```
import os, sys
import openpyxl
import pathlib

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, 
                             QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QCheckBox, QApplication, )

# from forma import form_MainWindow # форма
# class Example(QMainWindow, form_MainWindow):

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        # self.setupUi(self)
        self.initUI()

        self.tabl = Tabl()
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.tabl.setupTab(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabl, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn_che = QPushButton('Счет CheckBox')
        self.btn_che.clicked.connect(self.excelCheck)

        self.excelCheckBox = QCheckBox('Весь список')
        self.excelCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(self.excelCheck)
        self.excelCheckBox.setChecked(True)

        self.statusBar().insertPermanentWidget(1, self.excelCheckBox)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.btn_che)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def excelCheck(self):
        try:
            # print(f'main.py > class Example > def excelCheck > выбраны строки c номерами {xx}')

            items = []
            for i in range(self.tabl.tableW.rowCount()):
                for j in range(self.tabl.tableW.columnCount()):
                    item = self.tabl.tableW.item(i, j)
                    if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                        items.append(item)

            for it in items:
                r = it.row()
                c = it.column()
                v, h = self.tabl.tableW.horizontalHeaderItem(c).text(), self.tabl.tableW.verticalHeaderItem(r).text()
                print(h, v)
        except Exception as check:
          print('ошибка! = ', check)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class Tabl(QWidget, object): # Сбор таблицы из excel файла
    def setupTab(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(parent)

        self.tableW = QTableWidget(self)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.tableW)

        file = pathlib.Path("testing.xlsx")
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file), read_only=True)
        ws = wb.active

        try:  # закрыть (file .xlsx) после работы
            headers = [item.value for item in ws[1] if item.value is not None]
            data = ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=9, max_row=100)

            self.tableW.setColumnCount(len(headers))
            self.tableW.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)

            for x, rows in enumerate(data):
                if rows[0].value is not None:

                    self.tableW.setRowCount(self.tableW.rowCount() + 1)
                    for y, cell in enumerate(rows):
                        val = cell.value
                        if val is not None:
                            item = QTableWidgetItem(str(val))
                            self.tableW.setItem(self.tableW.rowCount() - 1, y, item)
                            self.tableW.resizeColumnsToContents()  # ширина столцов подогнать по ширине текста

            for i in range(self.tableW.rowCount()):
                ch = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(parent=self.tableW)
                ch.setChecked(True)
                ch.clicked.connect(self.stateCh)
                self.tableW.setCellWidget(i, 0, ch)
                print(f'main.py > class Tabl > строка {i+1} - ch.isChecked() =', ch.isChecked())

        finally:
            wb.close()
            print(f'main.py > class Tabl > Файл {file} закрыт')
            print()
        return

    def stateCh(self):
        ch = self.sender()
        ix = self.tableW.indexAt(ch.pos())
        xx = ix.row() + 1
        print(f'main.py > class Tabl > Строка {xx} статус {ch.isChecked()}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(350, 250)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, не задавайте много вопросов. Вопрос, который вы задаете, должен рассматривать ОДНУ проблему.

Я не смог прочитать ваш **testing.xlsx**, поэтому нарисовал свое.

Я попробовал ответить на ваш вопрос: "Необходимо для дальнейшей обработки определить, какие строки помечены CheckBox" и некоторые другие вопросы.

Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте НОВЫЙ вопрос.

```
import sys
import os
import openpyxl
import pathlib

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, 
    QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QCheckBox, 
    QApplication, QAbstractItemView)


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def edit(self, index, trigger, event):
        # редактирование не разрешено только для первого столбца
        if index.column() == 0:
            trigger = self.NoEditTriggers
        return super().edit(index, trigger, event)
        
# -----------------> vvvvvv   ??? <-----------------------------   
#class Tabl(QWidget, object):                       
class Tabl(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                # +++
        super().__init__(parent)                                    # +++
        
        
    def setupTab(self):                                     # ??? , parent=None):              
# ???        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
# ???        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(parent)

#        self.tableW = QTableWidget()
        self.tableW = TableWidget()                                 # +++

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableW)

        file = pathlib.Path("testing.xlsx")
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file), read_only=True)
        ws = wb.active

        try:  # закрыть (file .xlsx) после работы
            headers = [item.value for item in ws[1] if item.value is not None]
            data = ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=9, max_row=100)

            self.tableW.setColumnCount(len(headers))
            self.tableW.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)

            for x, rows in enumerate(data):
                if rows[0].value is not None:
                    self.tableW.setRowCount(self.tableW.rowCount() + 1)
                    for y, cell in enumerate(rows):
                        val = cell.value
                        if val is not None:
                            item = QTableWidgetItem(str(val))
                            self.tableW.setItem(
                                self.tableW.rowCount() - 1, y, item)
                            self.tableW.resizeColumnsToContents()  
                            
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            for i in range(self.tableW.rowCount()):
                ch = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i+1))
                ch.setFlags(ch.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                ch.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
# ------------------------> vvvvvvv               
                self.tableW.setItem(i, 0, ch)
            self.tableW.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            
        finally:
            wb.close()
            print(f'main.py > class Tabl > Файл {file} закрыт')
            print()
        return


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
#        self.initUI()
        
        self.tabl = Tabl(self)                                 # + self
        self.tabl.setupTab()                                   # - self.centralWidget
        
        self.initUI()                                          # +++
        
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabl, 0, 0, 0, 0)


    def initUI(self):
        self.btn_che = QPushButton('Счет CheckBox')
        self.btn_che.clicked.connect(self.excelCheck)

        self.excelCheckBox = QCheckBox('Весь список')
        self.excelCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(self.state_changed)  # !!! state_changed
        self.excelCheckBox.setChecked(True)

        self.statusBar().insertPermanentWidget(1, self.excelCheckBox)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.btn_che)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def state_changed(self, state):
        if state:
            for r in range(self.tabl.tableW.rowCount()):
                item = self.tabl.tableW.item(r, 0)
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        else:
            for r in range(self.tabl.tableW.rowCount()):
                item = self.tabl.tableW.item(r, 0)
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def excelCheck(self):
        items = []
        for r in range(self.tabl.tableW.rowCount()):
            item = self.tabl.tableW.item(r, 0)
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                items.append(item)

        for it in items:
            r = it.row()
            c = it.column()
            v = self.tabl.tableW.horizontalHeaderItem(c).text()
            h = it.text()
            print(f'row={r} / Header = `{h}`; column={c} / Header = `{v}`')
        print()    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(350, 250)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо что уделили время, интересное решение.

Comment: @Tusher пожалуйста.

Comment: К сожалению, первый столбец таблицы тоже менять нельзя.